# Invert col2rgb and rgb2hsv

Tags: r, colors, hsv

I’m converting colours to HSV in order to remap the colour. In fact, I am generating a gradient of grey colours with `gray.colors`:

```
(mydata <- 1 : 10) # For exposition only
cols <- gray.colors(max(mydata))
```

However, what I actually want is a gradient of white–red instead of white–black. A bit of fiddling with the colour picker has convinced me that for this it should be enough to swap the value and saturation on the greyscale colours and then set the value to 1 (the hue of 0 already corresponds to red).

Nothing’s easier:

```
hsvc <-rgb2hsv(col2rgb(cols))
hsvc['s', ] <- hsvc['v', ]
hsvc['v', ] <- 1
```

However, in order to plot these values I now need to convert them back to R colour values. I don’t seem to be able to do this because of a missing `hsv2col`. Sure, there’s `hsv` which purports to do this but you cannot call it with the value of `hsvc` above – not even with a single column:

```
hsv(hsvc[, 1]) # plots *three* (wrong) colour values instead of one
```

And R cannot use the HSV values directly:

```
plot(1, 1, pch = 20, col = cols[1])   # Works, grey dot
plot(1, 1, pch = 20, col = hsvc[, 1]) # Nothing plotted
```

How do I get R-usable colour values back from the matrix of HSV values?

Comment: Why don't you use `colorRampPalette`? Something like `plot(1:10, pch = 20, col = colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(10)) `.

Comment: @Roland Because I didn’t think of it … incremental plot design and all that. I had the greyscale values and a collaborator asked me to make them red so I naturally though (I know, I can just fiddle with the HSV …)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `do.call` and `as.list` to pass the data to the relevant arguments of `hsv`:

```
do.call(hsv,as.list(hsvc[,1]))
[1] "#FFB3B3"

plot(1,1, pch=20, col=do.call(hsv,as.list(hsvc[,1]))) # light red dot
```

To do this for all you data:

```
plot(mydata,col=apply(hsvc,2,function(x) do.call(hsv,as.list(x)))) # a symphony of red
```

But it appears that the remapping has not worked correctly, since the intensity changes do not work in the same direction.

Comment: I fixed the colours by applying the transformation s=v-1 now, and leaving h and v unchanged. Better.

Comment: And just for completeness’ sake, since R is ostensibly a functional language: my implementation of `hsv2col` looks like this: `function (col) apply(col, COLS, lpartial(do.call, hsv) %.% as.list)` – `lpartial` and `%.%` are the left partial application and function composition, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
> do.call(hsv, as.list(hsvc[, 1]))
[1] "#FFB2B2"
```

But then you really need to generalise that to work on all columns of `hsvc`, so how about:

```
sapply(data.frame(hsvc), function(x) do.call(hsv, as.list(x)))
```

which gives

```
> sapply(data.frame(hsvc), function(x) do.call(hsv, as.list(x))) 
       X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8 
"#FFB2B2" "#FF9393" "#FF7C7C" "#FF6969" "#FF5858" "#FF4A4A" "#FF3C3C" "#FF3030" 
       X9       X10 
"#FF2424" "#FF1919"
```

or more nicely

```
> apply(hsvc, 2, function(x) do.call(hsv, as.list(x)))
 [1] "#FFB2B2" "#FF9393" "#FF7C7C" "#FF6969" "#FF5858" "#FF4A4A" "#FF3C3C"
 [8] "#FF3030" "#FF2424" "#FF1919
```

Comment: Sorry for being thick, but something like this would do the intended, right? ``col2hex <- function(col)
    apply(rgb2hsv(col2rgb(col)), 2, function (x) do.call(hsv, as.list(x)))
`` and ``col2hex(c("darkblue","darkred"))``